# Creating a template for projects in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to create a template that creates a project in RStudio with a few non-empty .R files and a directory.

So for example, I create a project named 'project1', I want it to create a regular project, with 3 .r files and a sub-directory.

So my project is located at ~/Desktop/MyProject/
and in this folder I'll have 3 files named file1.r, file2.r, file3.r and a directory called 'data'.

And also, in file1.r there will be the line `library(ggplot2)`.

I've tried reading the project template documentation written [here](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_project_templates.html) but I got lost a bit.

Comment: This is probably a better question for https://community.rstudio.com/